# Spinnaker: Delete old AMIs after successful deployment

Tags: spinnaker

Is there a native Spinnaker way to cleanup old AMIs after a successful deployment took place?
It's nice that the previous version of the newest deployment is available in AWS but the previous ones keep adding-up and thus incur not only cost but also confusion.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing native in Spinnaker. [Janitor Monkey](https://github.com/Netflix/SimianArmy/wiki/Janitor-Settings#setting-rule-of-cleaning-up-unreferenced-snapshots) will do this, however, and cleans up a bunch of other unused AWS artifacts.

It's very possible Spinnaker will support this natively in the future - just not right now.